# a simple javascript calculation to show result in a form field

Tags: javascript

i have a form field named ABC and i want to calculate its value and get the result at XYZ hidden field. I use rsform.

the calculation:

XYZ = ABC / 105 * 12

I don't have code knowledge please help in detail.
Thank you!

Comment: Displaying the relevant source code would be a good start. What do you have so far and what attempts have you made?

Comment: i have tried to write some code, which i googled, in javascript area but couldn't make it work. So i need to place this code at javascript area. The calculation it is simple as that i posted

Comment: If you display the source you have so far we have something to work we, we debug **your** source code and explain the reason(s) for it not functioning as intended and offer any solution(s) if we have them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add an `id` attribute to the form and hidden fields (the `id` attribute is added the same way as you assigned the `name` attribute) and:

```
document.getElementById('XYZ').value = document.getElementById('ABC').value / 105 * 12;
```

**Update**

A simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="ABC" value="10" />
    <input type="text" id="XYZ" value="" />
</body>
<script>
     document.getElementById('XYZ').value = document.getElementById('ABC').value / 105 * 12;  
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried it is not working. Is this possible to make this calculation in php?

Comment: You don't even need PHP to do this, but this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: if we code it in php then i can insert the code at the default value of the hidden field the XYZ

Comment: thanks for your replies i will ask at the forum of the component